# Does git reset --keep HEAD do nothing?

Tags: git

So, I have read that the `git reset --keep` works like `--hard` but remains unstaged changes.
So, if I just `git reset --hard`, I will get into the original `HEAD` state with clear index.
So, there is a question: Does the `git reset --keep HEAD` do nothing? Or what is the difference?
If I do the `git reset --keep HEAD~1`, will it work like there is no `HEAD~1` commit but I have made the changes on files?

Answer (score 2):

Does [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---keep) answer your question?

> ```
> --keep
> ```
>
> Resets index entries and updates files in the working tree that are different between <commit> and HEAD. **If a file that is different between <commit> and HEAD has local changes, reset is aborted**.

The `--hard` option forcibly overwrites local changes, and `--keep` ... keeps them ... by refusing to do anything that would overwrite a local change.

Comment: If I do the git reset --keep HEAD~1, will it work like there is no HEAD commit but I have made the changes on files?

Comment: It'll do what it says - if any file has local changes, that would be affected by the reset because they changed from `HEAD~1` to `HEAD`, then the reset will abort and nothing will be done

Comment: It sounds like you actually want `git reset --soft` or `git reset --mixed`, since neither will affect your un-committed local changes. The difference between them is just in how they track changes you already added but haven't committed yet.

Comment: Cheers for the edit @torek, I completely overlooked that